# retrieving values from complex types in entity framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm new to entity fraamework and am currently using EF 5.0. I just created my first complex type based on temp table that a stored procedure returns on execution. I'm stuck on trying to return this temp table. The following piece of code grabs and dumps the entire table into a gridview

```
PluggingTrack.DataSource = entities.TundishPlugging("01/01/2017", "07/01/2017")
PluggingTrack.DataBind()
```

My question is there any way to retrieve the table and then massage the values to create a custom gridview as opposed to the dump that I'm currently having to do? Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. The following dumps the entire temp table into a local variable

> Dim grades = entities.TundishPlugging("01/01/2017", "07/01/2017").ToList()

Then using a for each..next loop you can loop through the entries:

> For Each GradesTPR As TundishPlugging_Result In grades
>   Next